# Cannot load custom File System on Flink's shadow jar

Tags: java, jar, apache-flink, serviceloader, shadowjar

I needed some metadata on my S3 objects, so I had to override the S3 file system provided by flink.

I followed [this guide](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/deployment/filesystems/overview/#adding-a-new-pluggable-file-system-implementation) to the letter and now I have a custom file system which **works** on my local machine, when I run my application in the IDE.

Now I am trying to use it on a local kafka cluster OR on my docker deployment, and I keep getting this error `Could not find a file system implementation for scheme 's3c'. The scheme is not directly supported by Flink and no Hadoop file system to support this scheme could be loaded.`

I package my application using shadowJar, using the following configuration:

```
shadowJar {
  configurations = [project.configurations.flinkShadowJar]
  mainClassName = "dev.vox.collect.delivery.Application"
  mergeServiceFiles()
}
```

I have my service file in `src/main/resources/META-INF/services/org.apache.flink.core.fs.FileSystemFactory` that contains a single line with the namespace and name of my factory :`dev.vox.collect.delivery.filesystem.S3CFileSystemFactory`

If I unzip my shadowJar I can see in its `org.apache.flink.core.fs.FileSystemFactory` file it has both my factory and the others declared by Flink, which should be correct:

```
dev.vox.collect.delivery.filesystem.S3CFileSystemFactory
org.apache.flink.fs.s3hadoop.S3FileSystemFactory
org.apache.flink.fs.s3hadoop.S3AFileSystemFactory
```

When I use the S3 file system provided by flink everything works, it is just mine that does not.

I am assuming the service loader is not loading my factory, either because it does not find it or because it is not declared correctly.
How can I make it work? Am I missing something?